# Lighting Stays with Animated Surface in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, rotation, lighting, surface

I'm attempting to animate a rotating sphere in Matlab, however the lighting on the sphere rotates with it. I instead want the sphere to rotate while the lighting remains fixed with the coordinate system. Here's a gif of what my code is currently producing: [Animation](http://i.imgur.com/0Y8oJNS.gif). And here is my code:

```
% Simulation Time
dt = 0.05;
time = 0:dt:5;

% Prep Figure
figure('Color',[1 1 1],'Renderer','zbuffer','ColorMap', [1,0,0; 0,0,1])

% Generate Sphere
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(20);
r = 0.75*25.4;
h = surf(r*X,r*Y,r*Z,Z,'FaceColor','interp');
hold on

% Adjust Axes, Lighting, and Shading
axis equal
view([40 25]);
light('Position',[1 1 1])
set(findobj(gca,'type','surface'),...
            'FaceLighting','phong',...
            'AmbientStrength',.3,'DiffuseStrength',.8,...
            'SpecularStrength',.9,'SpecularExponent',25,...
            'BackFaceLighting','unlit','EdgeColor','k')

filename = 'Rotation.gif';
for n = 1:36

      rotate(h,[0 0 1],10,[0 0 0])
      im = frame2im(getframe(1));
      [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);

      if n == 1;
          imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf,'DelayTime',dt);
      else
          imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',dt);
      end

end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request. If a sphere spins around its own center and the colors (or light effect) stay still, then there is no animation any more. Unless you mean you want continents and oceans, added later, to spin? Otherwise you need to keep some color values still (= light) and rotate some other color values (=continents and oceans) and for each image you convoluate (multiplicate) both.

Comment: @Wli The question better seems to be:  "Why the light object set in absolute coordinate system at '[1 1 1]' seems to rotate with the sphere. Indeed rotate is called only for the sphere object, not for the light object". I have checked the position of the light in the loop, it never change. So, for the good or for the bad, it seems like matlab is not updating the light effects after the call to rotate (which is not intuitive).

Comment: Seems like it might be an issue with the surface `VertexNormals` not updating. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35210-rotate-m-function-fixed

Comment: @CitizenInsane clarifies my question. The weird thing is, this only happens when rotating about the z-axis. Here's an animation comparing z- and x-axis rotations: [Animation 2](http://i.imgur.com/LtDq89R.gif). As can be seen, the lighting sticks with the sphere when rotating about z, but stays with the axes when rotating about x.

Comment: @nkjt that was the issue! I tried out the updated rotation function you linked, and it solves the lighting problem. Thanks! [Animation 3](http://i.imgur.com/HXUwwLJ.gif)

Comment: @nkjt and joshchab, This was an interesting issue and nice fix.

Comment: @nkjt Maybe post an answer so that joshchab can accept it and thus remove the question from the "unanswered" tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments:

> Seems like it might be an issue with the surface `VertexNormals` not
>   updating.

The solution was to download the [rotate.m function fixed File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35210-rotate-m-function-fixed) submission.

The description:

> Bug evidence:
>
> ```
> [x,y,z] = sphere(20); 
> hs=surf(x,y,z,'facecolor','y'); 
> view(2) 
> axis equal 
> hl=light; 
> lightangle(hl,0,0) 
> % light is on -Y axis, thus at the 
> % bottom 
> rotate(hs,[0 0 1],30) 
> % rotate sphere to the right from 30°
> ```
>
> It looks like the light has moved. This is due to a bug in rotate.m
>   function. The "VertexNormals" property of the surf object is not
>   updated as "xdata", "ydata" and "zdata" properties are.
>
> This is fixed in the submitted version of rotate.m.